# Wordcount Example on GCP Stuck

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I followed the examples on https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/create-pipeline-go for both Python as well as Go but when I deploy the job to Dataflow, the job doesn't progress past 0% for >20mins.

Is there any known issues for Dataflow that prevent completion of this job?

The options I used to execute the job:

```
python -m  apache_beam.examples.wordcount \
             --input gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt \
            --output <output_bucket> \
            --runner DataflowRunner \
            --project <project_id>  \
            --region us-west1 \
            --tmp_location <gcp_tmp_bucket> \
            --service_account_email=<service_account> \
            --subnetwork=<subnetwork_path>
```

Comment: Did you actually replace the `<project_id>` with your project id? And same for the other parameters. To learn anything about what happened with this job, you should check the logs through the Dataflow console. Paste them here and maybe the question will be answered and be useful for other people.

Answer (score 0):

Your job is stagnating because you haven't filled in the values in the example command

Cancel the job, the job should timeout if it doesn't detect anything happening but you are billed for the worker that's running while it's stuck.

- You need to create a GCS bucket: this is passed to `--output "gs://yourbucket/output"`
- You need to specify your current project in GCP `--project your_project`
- Change the region if you are not working out of `us-west1` in `--region`
- You can specify a subpath of the bucket you created earlier for `tmp_location`: `--tmp_location "gs://yourbucket/tmp"`
- A service account is optional - leave this out and it will use the default Compute Engine service account.
- A subnetwork is optional as well, leave it out and Dataflow will use the default subnetwork (and each worker will have a public IP).

Fill these options in the command and re-run.